# Save file to server

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to download and save file from External server to my server for example :

- The user will enter the following link http://server8.mp3quran.net/ahmad_huth/019.mp3 then      click upload.
- I need to download and save the specified file to my server.

Comment: I didn't have any background about that can this class help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have a look at the `WebClient` class.

```
public void Download(string url, string filenameToSaveAs)
{
   WebClient wclient = new WebClient();
   wclient.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), filenameToSaveAs);
}
```